# mysql count and join

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I want to retrieve table with total count from multiple table and joins

I have 4 wordpress custom database tables.

**wp_tutorials**

```
ID          tut_name  
1            php               
2            mysql              
3            wordpress
```

**wp_chapters**

```
ID      tut_id     chapter_name   
1       1           php1
2       1           php2
3       2           mysql1
4       2           mysql2
```

**wp_series**

```
ID     chapter_id    series_name
1         1           php1A
2         1           php1B
3         2           php2A
4         2           php2B
5         3           mysql1A
6         3           mysql1B
7         4           mysql2A
8         4           mysql2B
```

**wp_tut_users**

```
ID    series_id     user_name   
1     2               user1
2     2               user2
3     4               user3
4     6               user4 
5     7               user5
```

---

from these four tables I want to retrieve by sql query following table.

## 1. tutorial

```
 tut_name        total_users
   php                3
   mysql              2
   wordpress          0
```

expecting best ways...

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you managed to join the tables together?  Do you know what a `group by` clause is and does?

Comment: i think i am trying to joining tables wp_tutorials and wp_tut_users with total user count.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `left join` to get even tutorials with no users

```
select t.tut_name, count(u.id) as total_users
from wp_tutorials t
left join wp_chapters c on c.tut_id = t.id
left join wp_series s on s.chapter_id = c.id
left join wp_tut_users u on u.series_id = s.id
group by t.tut_name
```

Comment: yes. the code is tested and working. this is what i am expected. thanks